# reading by columns using ptr

Tags: c

if I want to print by rows of

```
char boo[] = 
     "abcd"
     "efgh"
     "ijkl"
     "mnop";
```

I'd go with

```
for(i = 0; i < 4; i++)
{
  char row[] = "";
  for(j = 0; j < 4; j+)
    printf("%c", *(boo++))
  putchar('\n');
  puts(row);

}
```

my question is how I can print columns so I get

aeim 
bfjn 
cgko 
dhlp

Comment: What's the purpose of row variable? You better take it out for clarity.

Comment: @qrdl  to see if there are any words in rows or columns. again, I don't have the control over how to declare boo[]. I could convert boo[] to 2D char array but trying to find a better way.

Answer (score 2):

Because it looks like a homework I'll just give you a clue.

Your `boo` is not an array of strings - preprocessor glues all adjacent string literals into one string so you got one string "`abcdefghijklmnop`"

You need to declare it as

```
char *boo[] = {"abcd", "efgh", ...};
```

Comment: @qrdl -thanks but I really don't have the control over how to declar boo[]

Comment: That it's a different story - you need to print 0, 4, 8, 12, then 1, 5, 9, 13 and so chars from the string. You got the point?

Comment: The solution is obvious. You also need to put some effort into this - do not expect SO crowd to solve everything for you.

Comment: I don't expect you to solve unless you really want to. I just wanted to put it out there so I can talk about it also to see what happens. :)

Answer (score 2):

The other solutions involved modifying boo, which you said was against the rules, here a simple solution. Just use an inner loop which prints every 4th character relative to the outer loop.

```
int main() {
    int i, j;
    for(i = 0; i < 4; ++i) {
        for(j = 0; j < 4; ++j) {
            putchar(boo[i + j * 4]);
        }
        putchar('\n');
    }
}
```

think of it this way, this is effectivly manually treating boo as if it were a 2d array of characters. Since the formula for indexing a 1d array with 2d is (x + y * width), you can imagine that i is the x-coord and j is the y-coord.

Comment: no prob, in fact if you want to print things the old way, simply switch the i and j in the putchar statement :-P.

Answer (score 1):

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main (int argc, char* argv[])
{
    char *boo[] = {"abcd", "efgh", "ijkl", "mnop"};
    int i, j;

    for(i = 0; i < 4; i++) {
        for(j = 0; j < 4; j++)
            printf("%c", boo[j][i]);

        printf("\n");
    }
}
```

-m

Comment: Because it will compile and run.  What else would I give?

-m

Comment: it doesn't meet the requirements anyways, OP stated in a comment that he has no control over how boo is declared.

Comment: @fogus, for homework, clues--so he can learn from it and pass his course.

Comment: lol this is not homework. even if I were in school this is summer break :)

Comment: If people post homework questions on S.O. then it seem they care very little about learning anything.
-m